# MyOpenId login is not working

Tags: support, login

I have myopenid username and password. I already configure myopenid for logins and its shows in my logins.

[image: My Logins Image]

When I click on `add more logins...` and give same login url, its shows error

**No OpenID endpoint found.**

[image: No OpenID endpoint]

Comment: **Make another OpenID login ASAP.** Don't tell me you weren't warned: [myOpenID shuts down February 1, 2014; add an alternative login method to your account](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/190442/myopenid-shuts-down-february-1-2014-add-an-alternative-login-method-to-your-ac).

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy Thanks. I will add new logins.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign), as *MyOpenId has **shut down***.

This is not a problem with Stack Overflow, your OpenID provider doesn't exist anymore. See [myOpenID shuts down February 1, 2014; add an alternative login method to your account](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/190442/myopenid-shuts-down-february-1-2014-add-an-alternative-login-method-to-your-ac)

If you are still logged in now, **add another OpenID provider ASAP**.

If you logged out and can no longer log in, you'll have to contact the team with enough evidence about the account for them to let you back in. Your email address registered with the account is a minimum requirement here.

Comment: I was going to say that.